# How to categorize string values in BigQuery query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to categorize the column **"Name"** in Bigquery query.The table looks like as follows. I tried to solve the problem with `WHEN ... IN` command but I am getting an error code `303`. Can someone help me what I am missing here? Thanks

```
table: 

Value          Name
0.9           Room1,
0.1           Room2,
0.4           Room3,
0.23          Room4,
0.67          desk1,
0             desk2,
0.45          desk3,
0.85          desk4,
0.99          Sit1,
0.34          Sit2,
0.12          Sit3,
0.33          Sit4,
```

What I am expecting is:

```
table: 

Value          Name      Group
0.9           Room1,     Room
0.1           Room2,     Room
0.4           Room3,     Room
0.23          Room4,     Room
0.67          desk1,     Desk
0             desk2,     Desk
0.45          desk3,     Desk
0.85          desk4,     Desk
0.99          Sit1,      Sit
0.34          Sit2,      Sit
0.12          Sit3,      Sit
0.33          Sit4,      Sit
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT
  *
  , CASE
    WHEN Name in ("Room1",
                  "Room2",
                  "Room3",
                  "Room4") THEN Room

    WHEN Name in ("Sit1",
                  "Sit2",
                  "Sit3",
                  "Sit4") THEN Sit

    ELSE  Desk
  END AS Group
FROM table
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Syntax error: Illegal input character "\303"
```

Comment: Use single quotes for string literals, as in : `WHEN Name in ('Room1', 'Room2', 'Room3', 'Room4') THEN 'Room'`

Answer (score 0):

As @GMB mentioned in comments:

Use **single quotes** for string literals, as in : `WHEN Name in ('Room1', 'Room2', 'Room3', 'Room4') THEN 'Room'`

Posting the answer as *community wiki* since this is the best practice and for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.